# Powershell Script to Gather PC hardware details from existing Computers

Tags: powershell, networking, local, powershell-remoting

**Hi All**,

I was hoping if someone has done this scenario before. I'm looking for a PowerShell script to gather PC Hardware details in the local network. it's Windows 7,10 and not in DC.

Details I would like to get from each PC is

1. RAM (name and size)
2. CPU (name and size)
3. HDD (name and size)
4. Local User profiles

Is it something possible (logically I can't see how it's possible) as PC's are not in a domain.

Any suggestions would helpful

**Love & Peace 
My fellow humans**

Comment: If the device is not on the domain then how do you expect to identify them? Unless you're going to be physically on the machine, which at that point you may as well domain join the device, it will not be possible to pull data from it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$hdd = @()

$system = Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem
$cpu    = Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor
$users  = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "localhost" -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" |Select PSComputername, Name, Status, Disabled, AccountType, Lockout, PasswordRequired, PasswordChangeable, SID

$driveLetter = 'C'
$currentHdd  = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$($driveletter):'"

while( $currentHdd.DeviceID ) {

    switch( $currentHdd.DriveType ) {
        3 {
            $driveType = "HDD"
            break;
        }
        5 {
            $driveType = "Optical"
            break;
        }
        default {
            $driveType = "Other"
        }
    }

    $drive = $driveletter + ':   ' + $driveType + ("   {0:N2}" -f ($currentHdd.Size/1GB) + " GB  ") + ("{0:N2}" -f ($currentHdd.FreeSpace/1GB) + " GB  ")
    $hdd.Add( $drive )

    $driveLetter = ([char](++([byte]([char]$driveLetter)))).ToString()
    $currentHdd = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$($driveletter):'"
}

$ram = "{0:N2}" -f ($system.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + " GB"
$cpuName = $cpu.Name

"CPU:   $cpuName"
"RAM:   $ram"
"Disks:"
$hdd
"Users:"
$users
```

Comment: How does this target machines not on the domain?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for machines NOT on domain. 
You will need:

- IP Address(s)
- Admin login credentials for the remote machine

Below syntax will query Windows7-Windows10 machines for RAM, CPU, HDD and User profiles:

```
wmic /NODE:"127.0.0.1" memorychip get capacity & wmic /NODE:"127.0.0.1" cpu list brief & wmic /NODE:"127.0.0.1" diskdrive get Name, Manufacturer, Model & wmic /NODE:"127.0.0.1" useraccount get name
```

For the example above, I'm simply using loopback IP (queries the local PC you are on), but you can substitute any IP address. 


You can also specify your credentials to the wmic tool if needed. Learn more about wmic here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic